# How to avoid ResourcesExceeded in BigQuery with JOINs

Tags: join, pattern-matching, google-bigquery

I have the following query

    `SELECT domain, path, name, title_part, name_part FROM dataset.match_making_name_parts
    LEFT JOIN dataset.raw_title_parts ON LOWER(title_part) = LOWER(name_part)`

The problem I am trying to solve, is match making between a list of names (of assumed owners of specific web-sites) and names mentioned within the  tags and other such places at the raw HTML of a web-site in a given domain and path, which we have crawled.

I want to build a map of partial matches, so I can rank the matches according to some heuristics (how many name parts of the full name got matched, in how many uris and were there matches with other domains).

Example rows:

    `//raw_title_parts (domain, path, title_part):
    cloud.google.com, bigquery/query-plan-explanation, Query
    cloud.google.com, bigquery/query-plan-explanation, Plan
    cloud.google.com, bigquery/query-plan-explanation, Google
    cloud.google.com, bigquery/query-plan-explanation, Cloud
    cloud.google.com, bigquery/query-plan-explanation, Platform
    //match_making_name_parts (name, name_part):
    Google Cloud Platform, Google
    Google Cloud Platform, Cloud
    Google Cloud Platform, Platform`

I assumed, that using JOIN would be easier for the Query Planner, but turns out, it attempts to run the query with insane amount of Stages; the first two and last two perform other task, but most of the stages are just doing repartitions:

    `READ  $2, $1, $20
    FROM __PSRC___PA1_2
    WRITE  $2, $1, $20
    TO __PA1_REPARTITION2
    BY HASH($20)`

I have some ideas about alternative solutions to my problem, but this Resources Exceeded error comes around quite often and I would like to understand it more deeply.

What would be the best way to solve my problem in BigQuery? How can I better predict, which operations are problematic to the Query Planner of BigQuery and how to better use paradigms, that can avoid the problems?

EDIT: It seems that the problems start escalating relatively late on. With LIMIT 10000000, the query runs in 30 seconds, with LIMIT 1000000000 it no longer runs at all. Considering the numbers, this might be an issue with "memory pagination", that happens behind the scenes (does the set fit in RAM)?

Comment: Normally this indicates some kind of skew in the data. Can you try running e.g. `SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(LOWER(title_part), 100) FROM dataset.match_making_name_parts;` and see how many rows contain the most common title part(s)? If one part is very common, you can try filtering it out and see if the join completes.

Comment: Yes, I know now. The problem is, that my problems solution is dependent (heuristics) on also matching the very common matches. I am trying to build something, which starts from the bottom and tries to creep towards top from there (only using the popular matches, when the probability of match is high), but this is a much more complex model to build.

Would there be a simple way of refactoring my problem towards a direction, where the computational problem of the very common matches could be avoided?